# Creating a new variable in R that merges categorical entry options of two variables

Tags: r, variables, categorical

So I have one variable in my R dataset called "RACE" with different categorical race classifications. I also have another variable called "ETHNICITY" with different categorical ethnicity classifications. I want to create a new variable (new column) in my dataset called "RACE/ETHNICITY" that merges these two. For instance, if RACE is "Black" and Ethnicity is "Non-Hispanic" the corresponding entry under RACE/ETHNICITY column would be "Black Non-Hispanic."

What is the best way to go about this in R? Any help and sample code would be appreciated!

Comment: If your dataset is called `df` then ```df$`RACE/ETHNICITY` <- paste(df$RACE, df$ETHNICITY)```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `unite` in the tidyr package.

```
df |>
unite(race_eth, c("RACE","ETHNICITY"), sep = " ", remove = F)
```